# applying ssl for subdomains

Tags: ssl, subdomain, firefox

When I access my site by domain.com from firefox says "Connection is untrusted" and it says "the certificate is valid only for `*.domain.com"`.

But when I try to access the site `www.domain.com`, its resolving properly.

Firefox says,

> This Connection is Untrusted You have
>   asked Firefox to connect securely to
>   eduvision.tv, but we can't confirm
>   that your connection is secure.
>   Normally, when you try to connect
>   securely, sites will present trusted
>   identification to prove that you are
>   going to the right place. However,
>   this site's identity can't be
>   verified.
>
> What Should I Do?
>
> If you usually connect to this site
>   without problems, this error could
>   mean that someone is trying to
>   impersonate the site, and you
>   shouldn't continue.
>
> Technical Details
>
> eduvision.tv uses an invalid security
>   certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for
>   *.eduvision.tv
>
> (Error code:
>   ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
>
> I Understand the Risks
>
> If you understand what's going on, you
>   can tell Firefox to start trusting
>   this site's identification. Even if
>   you trust the site, this error could
>   mean that someone is tampering with
>   your connection.
>
> Don't add an exception unless you know
>   there's a good reason why this site
>   doesn't use trusted identification.

Is there any way to avoid this error,or shall we add  exception for this site.

Answer (score 1):

an SSL certificate is only valid for a given domain - this is typically either www.domain.com **OR** domain.com.  Wildcard SSL certs are also available (which it appears you have in this case) which will validate *.domain.com, including www.domain.com however still will not validate for domain.com.

Solutions would be:

- redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com (arguably better for SEO)
- purchase a further SSL cert

I invariably go for the 1st option which is easily acheived in IIS or Apache

Comment: The redirect will work, but it will only work without complaint if you hit http:// domain.com and get redirected to https:// www.domain.com.  If you have a cert only for www.domain.com, and you hit https:// domain.com", you will still get a warning that the certificate has a name mismatch before it gets redirected.

Answer (score 0):

> eduvision.tv uses an invalid security certificate.

This seems to indicate that your browsing is attempting to contact eduvision.tv, without the www.  Unfortunately the wildcard certificate doesn't match in this case.

I don't get any warnings if I go to www.eduvision.tv, which then redirects to the HTTPS-version.

So the obvious solution would be to make http://eduvision.tv redirect to https://www.eduvision.tv.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to get an SSL certificate from a provider that will add eduvision.tv as a SAN in the certificate. That way, it will work for eduvision.tv and any subdomain of eduvision.tv without getting any errors. I believe GoDaddy, DigiCert, and Comodo can do this.